# Calculate the nucleotide frequency of a given stretch of nucleotide stretch

Tags: r, string, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have a xyz.txt file in the given format below.

```
 AATGCC AAGAAA AAGGAA AAGGTA AAGCAG AAGCGA
```

All I want to do is upload it in the R environment which I did by this command:

```
library(Biostrings)

string <- read.table("/home/Folder/MY_FOLD/MYZ/mp.txt")
```

now as I am trying to get the frequencies of the four nucleotide sequences by this command:

```
st <- AAStringSet(string)    /this works fine in windows but not in linux/
```

the error is:

> ```
> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘XString’ for signature‘"data.frame"’
> ```

I am not able to figure out as to why this error is coming and where I am going wrong? How can I fix this error to get this pair of code working in LINUX platform?

Comment: Convert your data to a character string.The function cannot deal with data.frames.

Comment: What package are you trying to use? Is the same version of the package installed on both machines?

Comment: “Upload” implies sending data over a network connection to a server. What you mean is “load”, not “uploads”.

Comment: You may be interested in knowing that there exists a stackexchange site dedicated to bioinformatics: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kriti if any of the answers below helped solve your issue consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community that the answer worked to solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

As listed in [the documentation](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Biostrings/html/XStringSet-class.html), the function expects a character vector. After read.table, you have a dataframe. You could try the following:

```
data = read.table("test.txt")
string <- apply( data , 1 , paste , collapse = " " )
st <- AAStringSet(string)
```

Hope this helps!
Florian

Answer (score 1):

Your data, converted to data frame:

```
original <- "AATGCC AAGAAA AAGGAA AAGGTA AAGCAG AAGCGA"
original <- as.data.frame(original)
```

Let's assume this is a single DNA sequence, so remove spaces:

```
nospace <- df %>% mutate(original = gsub(" ", "", original))
```

**You actually want a `DNAString-class`**, which is a special class specific to the `Biostrings` package:

```
d <- DNAString(nospace$original)
```

To get table of 4-mer frequencies:

```
fourmer <- oligonucleotideFrequency(d, 4, step=1)

head(fourmer)
AAAA AAAC AAAG AAAT AACA AACC 
   3    0    3    0    0    0
```